# Redux-saga is not updating store states

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios, redux-saga

I'm using redux-saga to fetch an endpoint and want to present it on first page load using `useEffect()`. But mine is not fetching anything. The screen is blank and reduxDevTools is also not showing anything. I can't understand what did I miss.

My `saga`:

```
export function* watcherSaga() {
    yield takeLatest("FETCH_TOP_NEWS_REQUEST", workerSaga);}

function fetchTopNews() {
    return axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=API_KEY'
    });}

function* workerSaga() {
    try{
        const response = yield call(fetchTopNews);
        const news = response.data.articles;

        yield put({ type: "FETCH_TOP_NEWS_SUCCESS", news });
    }
    
    catch (error) {
        yield put({ type: "FETCH_TOP_NEWS_ERROR", error });
    }
}
```

I defined 3 **actions**:

```
const initialState = {
    fetching: false,
    error: null,
    news: []
};

const NewsReducer = (state=initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case types.fetchTopNewsRequest:
            return { ...state, fetching: true, error: null };
        case types.fetchTopNewsSuccess:
            return { ...state, fetching: false, news: action.news[0] };
        case types.fetchTopNewsError:
            return { ...state, fetching: false, news: null, error: action.error };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default NewsReducer;
```

At last my **component**, I imported the `fetchTopNewsRequest()` action here:

```
const TopHeadline = (props) => {
    const { news, getTopNews } = props;

    useEffect(() => {
        getTopNews();
    }, [getTopNews]);

    return (
        <div className="newsItem">
            <h1>Title: {news.title}</h1>
        </div>
    );}

const mapStateToProps= (state) => {
    return {
        news: state.news,
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        getTopNews: () => dispatch( fetchTopNewsRequest() )
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TopHeadline);
```

I'm trying to fetch only the `articles.title`.

DevTools shows it's successfully fetching the data:
[image: devtools-action-tab]

Buy my states are not updating:[image: devtools-states-not-updating]

Comment: Did you try console.log to see if the saga is executed and did you check the network tab to see if any xhr was made?

Comment: Yes, there is a row with status 200 in the XHR of network tab. What does it mean? Does my presentation component have any typo? Or is it not rendering the JSON?

Comment: And doing `console.log("");` inside `watcherSaga` and `workerSaga` is also showing on the console.